# Set An IBAction to disabled In Objective - C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have a button set up as an `IBAction` that i was to disable after it's pressed and re-enable it after 12 seconds. I have a bunch of timers set up in the `IBAction`. It's called moodButton. How do I disable this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable/Disable button using webViewDidFinishLoad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859580/enable-disable-button-using-webviewdidfinishload)

Answer (score 6):

I like the flexibility of @iBuntyM's answer.

Here's an even more flexible approach, using Grand Central Dispatch:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    button.enabled = NO;
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 12 * NSEC_PER_SEC),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        button.enabled = YES;
    });
}
```

**EDIT** Of course alot can happen in 12 seconds and when the timer fires you might find you don't want to re-enable the button any more.  Also it's difficult (impossible?) to cancel a dispatch timer if these conditions change before it fires.

Therefore perhaps using an `NSTimer`, stored in an instance variable, is a better approach as it can be cancelled (invalidated) if you change your mind/conditions change.

For example:

.h file:

```
@interface MyView : UIView {
    NSTimer *_reenableButtonTimer;
}

@end
```

.m file:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    _reenableButtonTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:12.0f
                                                            target:self
                                                          selector:@selector(reenableButton:)
                                                          userInfo:button
                                                           repeats:NO];
}

- (void)reenableButton:(NSTimer *)timer {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[timer userInfo];
    button.enabled = YES;
}
```

The `_reenableButtonTimer` can then be invalidated before fire time to cancel this re-enabling.

Answer (score 3):

On press action disable the `UIButton` and then you can use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`
 call another function and enable the `UIButton` again with `afterDelay` pass the delay time.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

    [sender setEnabled:YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(enableButton:) withObject:sender afterDelay:12.0];
}

-(void)enableButton:(UIButton *)button  {
    [button setEnabled:NO];
}
```

As there is no need to create `IBOutlet` for `UIButton` as another answer doing you can pass the `UIButton` object and change the property as required.

Comment: +1 This is a more flexible approach. However `true`/`false` should be `YES`/`NO`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes it is as The `TRUE` macro is only provided as backwards-compatibility with `C language Code`. Please correct me if i am wrong thank you

Comment: You were using `true`/`false` (which is C++), not `TRUE`/`FALSE`.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes you are right thank you for this point.

Answer (score 2):

Try with following code;

```
-(IBAction) buttonClickEvent:(UIButton *) sender
{
  sender.enable = NO;    
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:12.f target:self selector:@selector(moodButton:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Code of `NSTimer` method

```
- (void)moodButton:(NSTimer *)theTimer
{
   self.moodButton.enable = YES;
}
```

Comment: I think there is no need to create `IBOutlet` we can pass the `UIButton` object using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` with required delay time. please clear me if i am wrong. thanks

Comment: OK.. you are right but where i created IBOutlet ?? Thanks :)

Comment: `self.moodButton` as the `UIButton` created using Interface Builder as this thing remove now

Comment: self.moodButton is created object at elsewhere and i just use it.. m i right ?? please clear me if i am wrong. thanks

Comment: Yes if it is created programmatically. but it will be good if we good the pressed button objects directly

Comment: sorry friend please, can you explain me how it is better to pass object ? thanks :)

Comment: @iPatel : I think iBunty answer is better as think if you want to set 4 different buttons... using his code, its one time... for you you need to write `self.moodButton1.enable ...`, `self.moodButton2.enable ...`, etc...

Comment: @FahimParkar - yes you are right its better then mine answer but I was put answer as related to OP's question .. so for 1 button this code is same as iBunty . Thanks friend :)

Comment: @iPatel : nothing against you... but logically he is also right... support developer and enjoy coding...

Comment: @FahimParkar - thanks mate, i just want improve my knowledge nothing more :)

Answer (score 1):

Implemented the following:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button {
    button.enabled = NO; // Same as setting enabled property to self.moodButton
    [self performSelector:@selector(enableMoodButtonButton) withObject:button afterDelay:12.0];
}


- (void)enableMoodButtonButton:(UIButton *)button {
    button.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: You can pass the `UIButton` object using `withObject`

Answer (score 0):

You can put things conditional into your IBAction like

```
-(IBAction)pushMe {

   if(isThisActionAvailable) {

      [self doMyWorkNow];
   }
}
```